# assign Integer type to int

Tags: java, types, casting, type-conversion

Is there any problem (Run Time of course) in assigning `Integer` to `int`?

```
int x= Integer.class.cast(parameters.get("PO_PAGE_CNT"));
```

As `Integer` is the parent class and int is the instance, I think maybe in some cases I get `ClassCastException` or other type of Exception at run time. Is it right?

Comment: Unless you're using a very old JDK, the return value of `cast` will auto-unbox to an int and all will be well...

Comment: You can just `(int) parameters.get("PO_PAGE_CNT")`. Even better... You don't have to cast, you can `int x = parameters.get("PO_PAGE_CNT")`

Comment: @Jonk and what will happen with newer JDKs? they can't auto unbox? since what version it does not support this feature?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood me - all newer JDKs will auto-unbox and this will work fine. It's the really old JDKs (pre 1.5) that this won't work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no problem. Integer values are automatically unboxed to int values and vice versa.

There is one exception, though. If `parameters.get("PO_PAGE_CNT")` returns `null`, you'll get a `NullPointerException`, since there is no `int` equivalent to `null`.

Comment: All answers here are correct. but since you mentioned an exception, I chose yours as the correct and more complete answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `parameters.get("PO_PAGE_CNT")` returns an instance of `Integer`, there is no problem with this assignment.

It would be more readable to simply write :

```
int x = (Integer) parameters.get("PO_PAGE_CNT");
```

An int can always be assigned to Integer (Boxing) and vice versa (Unboxing).

Answer (score 1):

no problem. There is concept called boxing and unboxing. you can follow this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem. You are boxing and unboxing Integer. And there will be no **ClassCastException** if you are unboxing Integer to int